# Applet does not appear ont JFrame

Tags: java, applet, jframe

I am trying to add an Applet object on the JFrame and it is not visible.

Does anyone know what is the reason for this?

My JFrame constructor:

```
    TestApplet apl; 

    public RunnerMain() 
    {
        setTitle("File Generator");
        setSize(800, 1000);
        setResizable(false);
        apl = new RunnerGUI();

        Container cp = getContentPane();
        cp.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        cp.add(apl);
    }
```

My applet definition:

```
 public class TestApplet extends Applet implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener 
 {


    public void init() 
    {
        ...
        buffer = createImage(800, 800);
        doublebuffer = buffer.getGraphics();
        ...
    }
 }
```

Comment: What is `RunnerGUI`? How does it relate to `TestApplet`?

Comment: try overriding JApplet.
also, your applet is doing any custom painting anywhere? because just creating this buffer will not get anything visible.